# Gem server started but not viewable on front end

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I have recently installed Ruby 1.9.2 on Linux Ubuntu 10.04 running 0.7.65 when I run `gem server` the server starts but is not viewable on the 8808 port of the domain.  I have tried this with both the IP and the domain itself.

Am I missing a configuration for this? In the past it has always just worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried running `gem server` on my Ubuntu 11.04 server:

```
[mike@mike ~]$ gem server
Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8808
```

My server's IP address is `192.168.0.42`:

```
[mike@mike ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:09:27:ff:ff  
          inet addr:192.168.0.42  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

So I was thus able to hit my Ruby Gems server via `http://192.168.0.42:8808/`

Are you sure you're hitting your server at the correct IP address?  Is the server configured to listen on the interface you're trying to hit it through?  Is port 8808 being blocked by either a firewall or iptables (or something else, for that matter)?

Comment: I am hitting the correct ip address, and the only configuration i did was installing ruby gems.  I get the exact same output from my server that you do but cannot view the page.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: This ended up being a network issue.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mike -  I have a similar problem with the yard gem server which i am using on a windows machine. http://www.rubyinside.com/the-3-step-guide-to-slick-local-documentation-for-all-your-ruby-gems-3760.html . How the yard server is running, but can't be seen in a browser.